Memory management while loading python in C#
I am calling python function in C#. It loads deep learning model in C# framework successfully. However, i wanna release memory when task is done (for example detection/inference) but i am facing problem on it. I cannot release memory, as i wanna do other multiple tasks without closing an application. Currently I am  using PythonNet for it. So, when i click Button3, i wanna release memory but objects hold memory of 11 gb without releasing it. I need some suggestion. I have uploaded code here.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Python.Runtime;
using VOModel;`

public class Detection : IDisposable
{
    private PyObject model_object;
    private string model_path = string.Empty;
    private List<PyObject> model_objs = new List<PyObject>();
    private bool _disposed = false;
    private bool pythonEngineInitialized = false;

    public void SetEnvironment(string conda_path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(conda_path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(conda_path));
        }

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", conda_path + ";" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH"));
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", conda_path);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", conda_path + "\\Lib");
        PythonEngine.PythonHome = conda_path;
        if (!pythonEngineInitialized)
        {
            PythonEngine.Initialize();
            ClsModelMgr.Ins.BeginAllowThreads();
            pythonEngineInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    public PyObject LoadNet_OD(string vomodel_path, string weights_path)
    {
        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            model_path = vomodel_path;
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(vomodel_path);
            PyObject pyObject = Py.Import("sys");
            pyObject.GetAttr("path").InvokeMethod("append", new PyString(vomodel_path));
            dynamic val = Py.Import("loadnet_od");
            dynamic val2 = val.load_net(weights_path);
            model_object = val2;
            model_objs.Add(model_object);  // Ensure the model object is tracked for disposal
            Console.WriteLine("Load Done");
            return val2;
        }
    }

    public dynamic ExecutePythonCode(string code)
    {
        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            using (PyScope scope = Py.CreateScope())
            {
                scope.Exec(code);
                return null; // Modify as needed to return the result
            }
        }
    }

    public dynamic GetModelObject()
    {
        if (model_object == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Model is not loaded.");
        }

        return model_object;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                foreach (var obj in model_objs)
                {
                    obj.Dispose();
                }
                model_objs.Clear();

                model_object?.Dispose();
                model_object = null;

                if (pythonEngineInitialized)
                {
                    PythonEngine.Shutdown();
                    pythonEngineInitialized = false;
                }
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~Detection()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}

namespace Memory_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Detection od_model;
        PyObject model_obj_OD;
        bool pythonEngineInitialized = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Load
            string pypath = @"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38";
            string wpath = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\DL\best.pt";
            string vood_path = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\DL\VOModels";

            // Initialize Detection object
            if (od_model == null)
            {
                od_model = new Detection();
                od_model.SetEnvironment(pypath);
                pythonEngineInitialized = true;
            }

            try
            {
                Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();
                model_obj_OD = od_model.LoadNet_OD(vood_path, wpath);
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Time taken to load model: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred while loading the model: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReleaseMemory();
        }

        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            ReleaseMemory();
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
        }

        private void ReleaseMemory()
        {
            // Dispose of model_obj_OD if initialized
            if (model_obj_OD != null)
            {
                model_obj_OD.Dispose();
                model_obj_OD = null;
            }

            // Dispose of the Detection object
            if (od_model != null)
            {
                od_model.Dispose();
                od_model = null;
            }

            // If the Python engine was initialized, shut it down
            if (pythonEngineInitialized)
            {
                try
                {
                    PythonEngine.Shutdown();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while shutting down the Python engine: {ex.Message}");
                }
                finally
                {
                    pythonEngineInitialized = false;
                }
            }

            // Perform garbage collection to release any remaining resources
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
}

'Here is an image'
